# Cannot get ThreadStart and ParameterizedThreadStart to function correctly

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to learn multithreading in C#. I have a HW assignment in which we are using the producer/consumer example of threading from MDSN ([Found here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx)

From my understanding, `ParameterizedThreadStart` is the "same" as `ThreadStart`except for `ParameterizedThreadStart`having an `Object`parameter.

I have the following method, which I want to create a `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate with:

```
public void ThreadProdRun(int amount)
{
   cell.WriteToCell(amount, ref quantity);
}
```

And my call to `ParameterizedThreadStart` is as follows:

```
Thread producer = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart (prod.ThreadProdRun));
```

Which doesn't work because the overloads do not match. I cannot use an object in place of the parameter, or int because int is a struct in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `ParameterizedThreadStart` signature by pressing `F12` in visual studio.

It is `public delegate void ParameterizedThreadStart(object amount);`

Your ThreadProdRun method must have object as parameter

```
public void ThreadProdRun(object amount)
{
   cell.WriteToCell((int)amount, ref quantity);
}
```

**EDIT**
Example with lambda expression and closure

```
int amount = 1;
Thread t = new Thread(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(amount);
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to use a thread like I described without using a delegate?

Edit: Just saw your edit. Casting like that works fine?

Comment: No, there is no Thread empty constructor. But you can use labmda with closures. Look at my Edit